# View or log to see who has run a report

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, reporting-services

The client has SP 2013 with SSRS reporting integrated. I have built some reports for them and they work great. On one of the reports, the client would like to be able to see who has run the report as it is mandatory.

Is there a view I can set up that will display who has run this report? If not, can I use the Usage DB to create a log of who runs the report?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have [enabled auditing](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25428.sharepoint-2013-how-to-enable-the-audit-log.aspx) at the list/library level from settings page

Information management policy settings  -> Enable [Auditing](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/126012-how-to-track-changes-on-sharepoint-server-2013) -> Opening or downloading documents, viewing items in lists, or viewing item properties

If you have enabled this settings then go to [Audit Log reports](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/View-audit-log-reports-4293e8d5-4e7d-4201-b8ac-c8e63a100131) from the site collection site settings and then

Run a custom report --> Opening or downloading documents, viewing items in lists or viewing item properties.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this is to use the statistics that SSRS keeps. SharePoint's usage analytics are awful.

You can find usage stats using SQL Server queries by connecting to the SQL Server that hosts the ReportServer database (probably your SharePoint SQL Server in integrated mode) and query the table ExecutionLog or the views ExecutionLog2 or ExecutionLog3.

There are several sites and blogs on the web that provide various queries on how to get information from these in different forms. The most basic way is (obviously) using SSMS:

```
USE ReportServer
GO

SELECT * FROM ExecutionLog3
```

By default it keeps 60 days worth of stats but you can use Central Admin to keep them longer.

See:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/report-server-executionlog-and-the-executionlog3-view